# 511 limit for minor version is per item or per library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, versioning

I have gone through below link
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

> which says The maximum number of minor file versions is 511. This limit cannot be exceeded.

My Question here is, lets say I have document library (enabled for major and minor versions).

I add one document with 50 minor versions and then one major version.

By following this method when I will have 11th major version, by that time I have 550 minor versions for same document.

Is this possible?

In simple words, 511 limit for minor version is per item or per library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned here: [Introduction to versioning](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Introduction-to-versioning-49e87cfa-1f18-427b-852b-7ff1612ef672).

> By default, each major version can have up to 511 drafts (minor versions)

This should still hold true for SharePoint 2013.